# The Budgie application launch icons disappeared from the bottom of the desktop

Tags: unity

I run Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 LTS. Just today, when I booted my computer as always, I did not get the launch icons for apps (LibreOffice, Firefox etc.) at the bottom of the desktop. I think you know what I mean . You get these when you install Budgie and can add further apps. I like, that I can launch applications with a single click and have my 6 mostly used applications quickly at hand. The application icon in the top left corner is fortunately still here. The top taskbar is also still there (Network, sound, shutdown etc.) How can I get the bottom icons back?

Comment: Sorry for this! I thought it has to do with unity. I am still learning. Now I understand, that unity is an alternative to Budgie, right?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly tnx for helping me to regain my super user experience with Budgie.  I followed your valuable hints: I issued the command Plank and added Plank to Autostart. At least now I understand the FULL Plank story.Case closed. Thank you!

Comment: This is the only part of your answer that has any value. I issued the command Plank and added Plank to Autostart.  No one wants to read all this other verbiage to find the actual answer. You may want to edit this down quite a bit.